# Popup temporary form in the current one

Tags: .net, devexpress

I have one main form and another which I have to popup in the following code:

```
private void barButtonItemEditCopy_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupForm pop = new PopupForm();
        pop.Show();
    }
```

and I want when event itemclick happens to lock current form afret `pop.Show()` and after closing pop form to continue with the main one. Now when I hit itemclick event the whole function pass and after that I see the popupform and my main form from which I popup is still available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming PopupForm is a (`System.Windows.Forms.Form`) winform. `pop.ShowDialog()` would show a modal dialog, and lockup other form till this modal dialog is closed. [check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `pop.Show();` with `pop.ShowModal();`

This will lock your original form for any input before you have closed the modal form.

Comment: There is no suck a metod for selection - pop is defined normally:" public partial class PopupForm : Form"

Comment: @Dominating - Seems I'm misremembering. As Sanjeevakumar has answered, the correct method to call is `ShowDialog()`.